# Unable to upload a video file to aws s3 bucket from android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to upload files/images/videos to the AWS s3 bucket from android. Some of the videos are uploaded successfully but sometimes when I upload a video is not uploaded and throw the following error:

```
     com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to verify integrity of data upload.  Client 
     calculated content hash didn't match hash calculated by Amazon S3.  You may need to delete 
     the data stored in Amazon S3.
     2020-01-16 16:58:15.065 30740-30740/com.sirona.android W/System.err:     at 
     com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1985)
     2020-01-16 16:58:15.065 30740-30740/com.sirona.android W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.uploadSinglePartAndWaitForCompletion(UploadTask.java:277)
     2020-01-16 16:58:15.065 30740-30740/com.sirona.android W/System.err:     at 
     com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.call(UploadTask.java:115)
     2020-01-16 16:58:15.065 30740-30740/com.sirona.android W/System.err:     at 
     com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.call(UploadTask.java:60)
     2020-01-16 16:58:15.065 30740-30740/com.sirona.android W/System.err:     at 
     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
     2020-01-16 16:58:15.066 30740-30740/com.sirona.android W/System.err:     at 
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
     2020-01-16 16:58:15.066 30740-30740/com.sirona.android W/System.err:     at 
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
     2020-01-16 16:58:15.066 30740-30740/com.sirona.android W/System.err:     at 
     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Here is my code

```
 private fun getS3Client(
        accessKey: String,
        secretKey: String,
        sessionToken: String
    ): AmazonS3Client? {

        var sS3Client: AmazonS3Client? = null
            try {
                val region: Region = Region.getRegion("us-west-2")
                val credentials =
                    BasicSessionCredentials(accessKey, secretKey, sessionToken)
                val clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration()
                    .withMaxErrorRetry(3) // 3 retries
                    .withConnectionTimeout(120000) // 120,000 ms
                    .withSocketTimeout(120000) // 120,000 ms

                sS3Client = AmazonS3Client(credentials, region, clientConfiguration)
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        return sS3Client
    }

            val observer: TransferObserver =
                transferUtility.upload(bucket_name, file.name, file,objectMetadata)
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: had the similar problem in java - what helped was sending `file.name.trim()` instead of `file.name`

Comment: I have tried this but this is not working.